# Eclipse plugin: how to show .* resources by default in perspective

Tags: java, perspective, eclipse-plugin, plugin.xml

How to configure perspective in plugin/RCP to show .* resources.

Currently, it should be done manually by selecting `Customize View...` by every user.

**In Eclipse plugin development how to show .* files in a new perspective by default?**

Related
[How to customize eclipse perspective programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159834/how-to-customize-eclipse-perspective-programmatically)

Comment: Do you want to show the .* resources in the *package explorer* or somewhere else?

Comment: Project Explorer actually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113234/how-to-change-eclipse-preferences-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to show the `*.`resources in the *package explorer*. I do not think there is any plugin designed to do exactly that, but you still have some possibilities.

A simple way to do it, is to go to `Customize View`. You can just select `Filters...` from the view menu (the shortcut to `.* resources` will be shown after you modify it):

[image: The filters menu.]

But of course you still need to do that for every user. If this is still too cumbersome you need to work with the extensions that defines them. You might have luck with creating you're own plugin that tries to overwrite the extension point that defines the filter. In short you have to add this to your `plugin.xml`

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaElementFilters">
    <filter
          targetId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer"
          name=".* resources (new)"
          enabled="false"
          description="Hides resources with names that start with a '.'"
          pattern=".*">
    </filter>
  </extension>
```

There is however a hack and there is no guarantee that this will work. If you look into `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.CustomFiltersActionGroup.CustomFiltersActionGroup(String, StructuredViewer)` you will see that it depends on the order in which the filter-extensions are loaded. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927357/override-existing-eclipse-plugin-extension) this is rather arbitrary.

Another way which requires more work, but is much less hacky and (to my best knowledge) is sure to work, is to modify the original extension point. This is defined in `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` so you have to replace this plugin. To do this you need to:

1. Import the plugin: Open the `Plug-ins` view, right click on
   `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` and select import as source
2. Find the extension in `plugin.xml` (Search for `name="%HideSystemFiles.label"`) and change `enabled="true"` to `enabled="false"`
3. Create a "feature patch" with you plugin. Export it and install into your Eclipse. (see resources below)

One disadvantage with this approach, is that you have to maintain this every time `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` is updated, essentially going through all steps again.

For more info on feature patches see:

- http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/30/patching-your-own-eclipse-ide/
- http://aniefer.blogspot.dk/2009/06/patching-features-with-p2.html
- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fproject_wizards%2Fnew_feature_patch.htm

Comment: Great post. I should have said that the perspective in question is not JDT related. It is defined as new https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/plugin.xml#L163-L171 (It seems like this way it ~~inherits from Resource perspective~~ shares the same setting with Resource perspective) Then there is PerspectiveFactory https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/src/org/nodeclipse/ui/perspectives/NodePerspective.java#L25 but I don't see needed methods when I type factory. (dot and see content assist).

Comment: IPerspectiveFactory is not leading to an answer...

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIPerspectiveFactory.html

Need to know exact name of attributes like in extension point="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaElementFilters"

Comment: Oh this is close http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_ide_resourceFilters.html

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceFilters">
  <filter pattern="*.class" selected="true"/>
 </extension>

Comment: That leads to generic Common Navigator Framework with no exact how to http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcnf.htm&resultof=%22Common%22%20%22common%22%20%22Navigator%22%20%22navig%22%20%22Framework%22%20%22framework%22

Comment: OK. To be sure: 1. Is it the filters in `Project Explorer` view you want to change?

Comment: Or perhaps the `Navigator` view

Comment: It is `Project Explorer`. Just like in `Resource` perspective

Comment: I *think* that `org.eclipse.ui.ide.resourceFilters` has to do with the (depricated) `Navigator` view from `org.eclipse.ui.ide`.

As far as I can see `Project Explorer` and its filters are defined in `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources` in the insanely large extension point `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` - just search for `.*` in the `plugin.xml`..... Let me know if that does the trick :)